# Page generation time tuning using NGINX

Tags: apache-2.2, nginx, php-fpm, migration

Most of the blogs I have encountered suggest to use **Nginx with PHP-FPM**. I have seen benchmarking results, and they all seem to be impressive, when compared to Apache with mod_php enabled. But fact worth noting about my case is that we serve **3RPS** at peak time. Changing Apache with Nginx is not an easy process. Maybe somebody could give any advice, **if it is worth migrating** servers in our case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably not. You did not mention if 3 rps is for *dynamic* requests only or *all* requests. Even if you meant dynamic requests, I do not think the migration is worth your efforts.

I suggest the following migration path for you:

- When you feel your server is overloaded, you may start with Nginx frontend serving static content only and proxying to your existing Apache, it will give you some time to make familiar with Nginx, etc.
- And then later you replace Apache with PHP-FPM.